# Issues with subroutine Perl

Tags: perl, subroutine

I'm trying to execute a Perl program, but the window only closes up. But if I select a part of the window, it stays open, and I press *Enter* and says

> Undefined subroutine &genNumeros::crearNumero called at .... at line 17

#### genNumeros.pm

```
package genNumeros;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::Complex;

my $seed = time();
my $a = $seed / 5;
my $c = $seed - 7;
my $x = $seed;
my $m = sqrt($seed % 574) + $seed;
my $numAleatorio;


sub generadorMultiplicativo {
    $numAleatorio = ((($a*$x) + $c) % $m);
    $x = $numAleatorio;
}

my $letra;
my $residuo;

sub crearNumero {
    generadorMultiplicativo();
    $residuo = $x / $m;

    return int($residuo * 27)
}

1;
```

#### main.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

use FindBin;
use lib $FindBin::Bin;
use genNumeros;

my @palabra;

open (my $ARCHIVO, '<', "palabras.txt") or die ("No se encontro el archivo palabras.txt, $!");

while (my $palabra = <$ARCHIVO>) {
    chomp $palabra;
    push @palabra, $palabra;   
}

close $ARCHIVO;

my $palabraAleatoria = $palabra[ genNumeros::crearNumero() ];
print "$palabraAleatoria\n";
<>;
```

Comment: As your last line in script put getc; and let us know if that helps the window issue.

Comment: @mp3: Your comment is destructive. You are imagining that the OP is using Windows, and there will be thousands of people who come here with a similar problem who, sooner or later, will find that their code is subtly broken because an input character is missing. If you think you have an answer then please post an answer.

Comment: @Jairo: Your code works for me, apart from the vanishing window. You should open a `cmd` window and run `perl main.pl`, or whatever you have called your program file. What variant of Perl do you have installed?

Comment: Line 17 doesn't have a call to `genNumeros::crearNumero()`. What you posted isn't the code you ran!

Answer (score -2):

Your package name and the corresponding file name should use capital letters, and local names should be all lower case

So your library should be in file `GenNumeros.pm`, and should start with `package GenNumeros`

It should define subroutines `generador_multiplicativo` and `crear_numero`

Your main program file should `use GenNumeros`

The usual way to import identifiers is to use [`Exporter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exporter) in your library code, but fully-qualifying the subroutines, like `GenNumeros::generador_multiplicativo` is also fine